# python class and subclass calling order and inherent

Tags: python, class, inheritance, definition, calling-convention

I am new to classes in python and I met this problem which I did not find a similar question asked here. If you know which post or thread may have already answer this problem, please kindly let me know. Thanks in advance.

Here is the function. Define four classes, A, B, C and D.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
    def x(self):
        print ("A.x")
    def y(self):
        print ("A.y")
    def z(self):
        print ("A.z")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        self.a = 2
        self.b = 3
    def y(self):
        print ("B.y")
    def z(self):
        print ("B.z")

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        self.a = 4
        self.c = 5
    def y(self):
        print ("C.y")
    def z(self):
        print ("C.z")


class D(C, B):
    def __init__(self):
        C.__init__(self)
        B.__init__(self)
        self.d = 6
    def z(self):
        print ("D.z")

obj = D()
obj.y()
```

This was from an online resource. I am wondering why obj.y() print out C.y instead of B.y? Is this because in the class D(C,B): C was called before B so python match method y firstly with C but will not continue to look at method y in class B? Yet the values, a, b, c, d will be updated with the later calls.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In Python method **overriding** occurs simply defining in the child class a method with the same name of a method in the parent class. When you define a method in the object you make this latter able to satisfy that method call, so the implementations of its ancestors do not come in play.

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 5

    def get_value(self):
       return self.value

class Child(Parent):
    def get_value(self):
        return self.value + 1
```

ouytput:

```
>>> c = Child()
>>> c.get_value()
6
```

Comment: If the latter call overrides the former call, in my code, when define method for class D, "def __init__(self):
        C.__init__(self)
        B.__init__(self)" B.__init__ is called later than C.__init__, so it should use B definition on obj.y() so it should print out "B.y" but when you run the code, it actually prints out "C.y". What is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: As you mentioned above in the code, you are creating instance of class D and calling the function y(),however, class D is inherit the class C and B. Both c,b has function y(), so it will override the function of B and will print function of C.

Comment: thanks jack! but why it overrides B instead of C? I called B after C, should it override C?

Comment: You are totally misunderstood the concept of __init__ function. This will act  like a constructor.  consider obj = D() is created,it will directly call first __init__() function(so constructor). If you want to print B instead C then the code will be :class D(C, B):
    def __init__(self):
        
        b=B()
        b.y()
        
    def z(self):
        print ("D.z")

obj = D()
obj.y()   . You can refer tutorial to know more about __init__ function.

Answer (score 1):

Python use [MRO (Method Resolution Order)](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) to check which method will be called when used in inheritance.

You can check `__mro__` attribute of call to check, which class method will be called.

In your example

```
>>> D.__mro__
(<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>)
```

So when you call `obj.y()` it will check in `class D` then `class C` then `class B`.

Comment: So, it does mater if you write `class D(C, B): ` or `class D(B, C): `. It looks first on the left parrent.